# Why doesn't my comparison between two Integer-Values work?

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, multidimensional-array, integer

Sometimes values that aren't the same as the value compared to aren't being set to null, even though they do contain different values.
The values of the Array Values never changes, but the Value of the Array Results does.

```
static int[][][] Results= new int[1000][30][3];
public static int[] Values= new int[3]; //is in a different class

...

for (int i = 0; i < Results.length; i++) {

if ((Results[i][0][0]) != (Input.Values[0])
                    && (Results[i][0][1]) != (Input.Values[1])
                    && (Results[i][0][2]) != (Input.Values[2])) {

                Results[i] = null;
            }else{
                System.out.println(i+ " Results: " + Results[i][0][0] + " " +Results[i][0][1]+ " " + Results[i][0][2]+  " Values: " + Input.Values[0]  +" "+ Input.Values[1]+ " "+ Input.Values[2]);
            }
}
```

This is the Output:

...

*3 Results: 27 19 34 Values: 27 17 36*

4 Results: 27 38 15 Values: 27 17 36

5 Results: 27 38 15 Values: 27 17 36

6 Results: 27 23 30 Values: 27 17 36

7 Results: 27 23 30 Values: 27 17 36

8 Results: 27 46 7 Values: 27 17 36

9 Results: 27 39 14 Values: 27 17 36

...

E.g. in the 3. Output 27 is compared with 27 , 19 is compared with 17 and  34 is compared with 36.

What am I not seeing here? I've looked through other posts, but there the Problem was caused by e.g. comparing an Array that contains Integers to an Integer. I am pretty sure thats not the case here..

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your if statement.  Change your conditions to `||` and not `&&`. The 27 is the common number to all of your problems. With the `&&` they ALL must be different.